# How do I pass button as a parameter to a function?

Tags: javascript, webforms

I have a function that calls another function. My goal is to pass button as a parameter to another function.

```
function A(){
    var btn = $find("<%=btnX.ClientID %>");
    B(btn);
}

function B(*btn parameter here*){
//I need button here
}
```

Comment: `function B(btn) { ... }` is fine. Are you running into errors? What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sort of dont even have a issue since it should already work...

```js
function A(){
    // var btn = $find("<%=btnX.ClientID %>");
    btn = "test" // remove this "test" line
    B(btn);
}

function B(button){
//I need button here
console.log(button)
}

A()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should just work. Do you see any errors there?

```js
function A(){
    var btn = $find("<%=btnX.ClientID %>");
    B(btn);
}

function B(button){
  // Do with that button whatever you want here. E.g.
  button.style.color = 'cyan';
}

A()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with any selector. It should just work

```
function A(){
    var btn = "#btn";
    B(btn);
}

function B(button){
  // Do with that button whatever you want here. E.g.
  var btn = document.querySelector(button);

  btn.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  btn.style.color = 'white';
}

A();
```

```js
function A(){
    var btn = "#btn1";
    B(btn);
}

function B(button){
  // Do with that button whatever you want here. E.g.
  var btn = document.querySelector(button);
  
  console.log(button);
  
  btn.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  btn.style.color = 'white';
}

A();
```

```html
<button id="btn0">click button</button>
<button id="btn1">click button</button>
```